# I have a probability of $\frac{24}{800000}$ to win with one lottery ticket. What if I buy two tickets?

Tags: probability

Assuming there's a lottery with 800,000 tickets and 24 of these tickets contain a win, my chance to win (if I buy only one ticket) is $\frac{24}{800,000}$ or $\frac{1}{33,333.\overline{3}}$, right?

But what are my chances to win if I buy two tickets?

Comment: HInt: compute the probability of NOT winning.

Comment: $33000$ is a really poor approximation to $100000/3$.

Comment: @TonyK: Oh yeah. Obviously it's 33,333.$\overline{3}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I buy 2 lottery tickets do I double my chance of winning?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369659/if-i-buy-2-lottery-tickets-do-i-double-my-chance-of-winning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chances to win at least once are roughly twice as high if you buy two tickets.  Not exactly twice, because there is a very small chance both tickets will win, but this is small enough to ignore in an approximation.

Comment: So that would mean the chance that I will win is now roughly $\frac{1}{16,666}$? And if I buy 10 tickets, will it be $\frac{1}{3,333}$? That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: That is, roughly, correct.  However, if you buy 10 tickets, the probability of more than one victory from those 10 becomes much larger, so it's actually significantly less than $\frac{1}{3,333}$.

Comment: @4242 the **exact** calculation can be done via routine counting methods.  If we want the probability of **not** winning after having bought $k$ *different* lottery tickets it will be $\frac{\binom{800000-24}{k}}{\binom{800000}{k}}$ where $\binom{n}{r}$ is the binomial coefficient $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.  The probability of winning at least once will be one minus that amount.  For ten tickets that [evaluates to](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+(799976+choose+10)%2F(800000+choose+10)) approximately $0.0003$, similar to $1/3333$ but not exactly.