# Relationship between probability and odds

Tags: probability

While I'm reading *Weird Maths: At the Edge of Infinity and Beyond* by David Darling and Agnijo Banerjee, I found this part that I can't understand.

> Of course,  it’s extremely unlikely that you’ll win the jackpot twice.
> But when considering the probability that someone will,  you need to
> multiply the odds by the number of people  who play the lottery, which
> greatly reduces those odds, as  well as the number of ways they can
> win the lottery twice  (approximately half the square of the number of
> times  they play the lottery). After all of this, the odds look much
> more reasonable that someone, somewhere will scoop the  jackpot twice.

I know the odds is p/(1-p), but still don't understand why the authors did this multiplication.

If you need more text, you can find [here](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=uB69DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT49&lpg=PT49&dq=%22of+course,+it%27s+extremely+unlikely+that+you%27ll+win+the+jackpot+twice%22&source=bl&ots=lCmwpGUKH-&sig=ACfU3U0d0_NCeCoOHOp_rO-dVI7FGl628A&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNocjU_MvvAhWJv5QKHaTrAqkQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22of%20course%2C%20it%27s%20extremely%20unlikely%20that%20you%27ll%20win%20the%20jackpot%20twice%22&f=false).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233269/probability-of-winning-the-lottery-twice

Answer (score 1):

I don't think working with odds instead of probabilities improves understanding in this problem, so here is an answer using probabilities.

Suppose we have $n$ people playing the lottery, with each having a probability $p$ of winning, independently of all the other players.  Then the total number of winners has a Binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, so the probability that there will be exactly two winners is
$$\binom{n}{2} p^2 (1-p)^{n-2}$$
Now
$$\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
so for large $n$,
$$\binom{n}{2} \approx \frac{n^2}{2}$$
Also, for large $n$ and small $p$, $(1-p)^{n-2} \approx 1$.

Combining these approximations, we see the probability of having exactly two winners is approximately
$$\frac{n^2 p^2}{2}$$
which seems to be what the quoted text is getting at.